# .Include() derived class of specific Type?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

What's wrong with this Lambda query? I want to be able to only include ProjectDocs of a certain type, there could be many types of ProjectDocs

```
 ICollection<Project> projects = db.Projects
      .Include(i => i.ProjectDoc.OfType<Cover>().Where(s => s.Status == "Active"))
      .Include(i => i.ProjectDoc.OfType<Summary>().Where(s => s.Status == "Active"))
      .Include(i => i.User)
      .Include(i => i.ProjectTag.Select(t => t.Tag)).ToList();
```

I have a model ProjectDoc with the derived classes Cover, Segment and Summary. Should I just include ProjectDoc and use the discriminator column in a condition later? Some of the types could have a large number of results, others just a few.

The Error I get...

```
 The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined 
 on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the 
 Select operator for collection navigation properties.
 Parameter name: path
```

The Navigation Property on "Project" is ProjectDoc. There is no navigation property for the derived classes. When I tried that I got tons of extra keys.

Comment: Have you got any errors?

Comment: @Hamlet, added the error to the main question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scenario is not supported - you can only load or not load a set of related entities but you can not apply filter expressions to load only a subset of the entities.

The [API documentation for `Include()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236) lists the different expressions that are supported and states that the method just delegates the work to an underlying `Include()` method taking a string as argument, for example [`ObjectQuery.Include()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx). The documentation of this method and the linked page [Shaping Query Results](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx) make it more or less obvious that this is not supported.

Comment: Ok, so lets say I get to a view how do I apply derived class filters in the view?

Comment: Depends on your inheritance model - with TPH for example you could just filter on the discriminator column.